# Conditional Regular Expression to match a specific pattern or anything else

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm stuck trying to figure this out. 
I need a regular expression to check user input (text field) for the following:

- wherever there's a straight 6-digit number (`123456` and not `123,456`, `$1234.56`), it has to be preceeded by `LEG` (upper case only). If not preceeded by `LEG`, the input is invalid
- if there is nothing matching the above, it's valid

Test cases:

```
Invalid: "LEG181234 & 123678 & LEG"
Invalid: "hello 012345 world"
Valid: "hello LEG012345 world"
Valid: "LEG123456"
Valid: "Not Legged"
Valid: "01234"
```

So I've managed this expression:

```
(?<=[LEG])([0-9]{6})
```

which does the look behind to see if there's `LEG` if it finds 6 digits. But from there I'm stuck because I'm not sure how I can say "match anything else except 6 digits".

Would love any assistance!

Comment: Does this have to be done in one regexp? It would be easier with `if (<test for LEG+6digits> || <test for no 6digits>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your input to see if it's invalid like this:

```
(?<!LEG)\d{6}
```

Whenever there's a match, that means that there are 6 straight numbers not preceded by `LEG`. So, from your test cases, the first two would return a match.

Now, you didn't provide any other cases, but I wonder if there may be more. For instance:

```
BOOTLEG123456
LEG123456ABC
```

Are these allowed? If not, then you can use the [word boundary anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` and add two more checks:

```
(?<!LEG)\d{6}|\BLEG\d{6}|LEG\d{6}\B
```

So, along with the first one `(?<!LEG)\d{6}`, now you have the second one `\BLEG\d{6}` which looks for invalid characters preceding your accepted format and the third one `LEG\d{6}\B` matching the existence of invalid characters at the end.